# python: gevent's monkey.patch_all makes subprocess.check_all much slower

Tags: python, subprocess, gevent

Here is the test script:

```
from gevent.monkey import patch_all; patch_all()
import subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT                                                                        
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import datetime

with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    print('Subprocess call at {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    ret = subprocess.check_call(['iptables', '-t', 'mangle', '-L', '-vx'], stdout = f, stderr = STDOUT)
    print('Subprocess call end at {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

With `patch_all`, the execution time is usually about 600ms, and that without `patch_all` is only ~30ms. Therefore, I was wondering what makes this happen, and what can I do to reduce the latency?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1188) of `gevent` itself. Maybe the only thing I can do is to either rollback it to `1.1a1` or wait for `1.3b2`. Another solution could be passing `subprocess=False` to `patch_all()`